# Unable to get data from My Android App to Web application

Tags: java, android, web-applications, connection

I built an application in two ways:

1. Android
2. Web application (Dynamic web project built in jsp+servlet).

My goal is to fetch data from my android app to my hosted web application.

I'm able to send data from local webpage to the hosted Web application & able fetch data from the Android app (which is running in a mobile handset) to my localhost (when my Dynamic Web project is running on localhost).

I'm unable get data from the Android app (.apk file installed in a stand alone device) to my hosted Web Application.

Why am I unable to get data from android app to my hosted web application?